# Can the same structures allocate different memory sizes in C++?

Tags: c++, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

My structure code is like this:

```
typedef struct Patterns {
    int pattern_num;
    char *chained_fail_log;
    Patterns *next_pattern;
} Pat;
```

I made this structure for the linked-list, and the linked-lists are allocated by "new"

```
for( int num_of_pat = 1; num_of_pat < number_of_pattern+1; num_of_pat++) {
            curpattern->next_pattern = new Pat;
            curpattern = curpattern->next_pattern;
            curpattern->next_pattern = NULL;
            curpattern->pattern_num = num_of_pat;
            curpattern->chained_fail_log =  new char[chain_cell_length+1];
            for(int i = 0; i < chain_cell_length; i++ ) curpattern->chained_fail_log[i] = '0';
            curpattern->chained_fail_log[chain_cell_length] = '\0';
}
curpattern->next_pattern = NULL;
```

I deleted the structure by delete.

```
`void Circuit_Fail_Log::freepattern() {
    Pat * delpattern = fail_pattern_log;
    int i = 0;
    while( delpattern != NULL ) {
            i++;
            fail_pattern_log = delpattern->next_pattern;
            printf("pattern_num:%d\tchained_pattern:%s\n",delpattern->pattern_num,delpattern->chained_fail_log);
                    delete[] delpattern->chained_fail_log;
                    delpattern->chained_fail_log = NULL;
                    delete delpattern;
            delpattern = fail_pattern_log;
    }
```

As you see in the code, the pointer for the next list cannot point to the next list in some cases.
I assume that the memory size of the list became bigger than the size when it was allocated.
So, the linked list pointer cannot point to the next list.

error message is

```
*** Error in `fextraction': double free or corruption (out):0x0000000001de9de0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x81679)[0x7f66390fb679]
fextraction[0x401ae4]
fextraction[0x401ed3]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f663909c505]
fextraction[0x4008d9]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your question isn't making sense to me. But in in the case of the very last `Patterns` object created, its `next_pattern` may point to anywhere.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SOF! Can you please provide an error message that can explain how and when your program fails?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I modified the code for the {next_pattern} to get a NULL

Answer (score 0):

It should not happen but actually you are doing it by writing to a memory address which does not belogs to `chained_fail_log`.
If `chained_fail_log` should have `chain_cell_length` characters length minus the null terminator then you should :

```
// one more for null terminator
curpattern->chained_fail_log =  new char[chain_cell_length+1]; 
for(int i = 0; i < chain_cell_length; i++ ) curpattern->chained_fail_log[i] = '0';
curpattern->chained_fail_log[chain_cell_length] = '\0'
```

In your original code `curpattern->chained_fail_log[chain_cell_length] = '\0'` is breaking memory boundry of your `chained_fail_log`

Comment: Thank you, I modified the code. but I still have the error message

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the answer.

In some cases, data was inserted in the curpattern->chained_fail_log[-1] on my program.

I fixed these cases, then the memory deallocation(delete) works without errors.